# How to make config folder shared across all ES nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We are setting up the ES on the GKE cluster using the installation steps provided in https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/elastic/elasticsearch/7.6.2

We are planning to introduce a synonyms.txt inside the /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ folder.

any one has idea how it can be made.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.,

1. I wanted to install a specific version of ES which is 7.9.2.
2. I created a values.yaml with a shared mount of Persistent volume with below content.

```html
---
extraVolumes: |
   - name: essynonyms
     persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: synonyms-files-nfs-pvc

extraVolumeMounts: |
   - name: essynonyms
     mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/analysis
```

3. Install the helm using below command. I have created with three replica.
   helm upgrade --wait --timeout=600s --install --version 7.9.2 --values ./values.yaml arc-elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch --set repl
   icas=3
4. Install the NFS using the setup procedure provided in the below line
   [NFS Installation Procedure](https://github.com/mappedinn/kubernetes-nfs-volume-on-gke)
5. Place the Synonyms file in the NFS location , It will be available across all the ES nodes.